# sorting the Students` Scores by priorityqueue in java

Tags: java, sorting, key, priority-queue

I have Student class. its main instance variables are Name,ID,Score.
what is the best way to sort the student objects by scores using proirityQueue?
or should i say, i heard the general PriorityQueue has Key and Value,i want my Key to be Scores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this construct your `ProirityQueue` passing it your implementation of `java.util.Comparator` that compares `Student` objects based on their score.

Then use `poll()` to feth next student with highest/lowest score (depending on how you define sorting rules in comparator) from queue.

You should get something like:

```
Comparator<Student> comparator = new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        return (int) (s1.getScore() - s2.getScore());
    }
};

Queue<Student> queue = new PriorityQueue<Student>(11, comparator);

// put some students into queue here ...

Student firstInQueue = queue.poll();
```

Have a look on [this tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1642/java-priority-queue-priorityqueue-example) for more detailed explanation of how to do this.

**UPDATE**: alternative way to do this is to make your `Student` implement `java.lang.Comparable`, as Edgar Boda suggests.

This approach might be more convenient if you want to apply the same sorting rule for all student objects, regardless of what queue (or list or anyting sortable) they are in. However, if you want to have different rules for different queues (for example when you have 2 queues, one based on score and another, based on name) approach with comparator provides more flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your `Student` class implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and then use the [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). Read the javadocs for details on how to do it.

Comment: Thanx,,, it seems that comparable implementer should have a Compareto method, and my problem is, i Dont wanna compare two things like x,y. i want the instance variable "Score" to be comparable.how would i do that?

Comment: the comparable is exactly what you want. You want to compare the score of your class. Read the javadoc and google for concrete examples on how to correctly implement the compare method.